# EndPointReference method

Tags: revit-api

I am strugglying with a problem that is to access the reference of the end point of a pipe curve to then create a dimension in the model, by the method doc.Create.Dimension().I already tried to use the Curve.EndPointReference(int index) method but it returns only null value. Can anyone help how to access this information ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also discussed and answered here by Fair59:

https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/revit-api-forum/endpointreference/td-p/7131328

The answer is also pointed to from The Building Coder:

http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2011/10/retrieving-duct-and-pipe-endpoints.html#comment-3344122037

Fair59's answer:

You probably are using the LocationCurve to find the reference. You need to use the "reference" Curve/Line that is part of the Element.Geometry.

```
Selection sel = this.ActiveUIDocument.Selection;
Element elem = doc.GetElement(sel.GetElementIds().FirstOrDefault());
Options opt = new Options();
opt.ComputeReferences = true;
opt.IncludeNonVisibleObjects = true;
opt.View = doc.ActiveView;
Reference ptRef =null;
foreach( var geoObj in elem.get_Geometry(opt) )
{
  Curve cv = geoObj as Curve;
  if (cv==null) continue;
  ptRef = cv.GetEndPointReference(0);
}
if (ptRef!=null)
{
  TaskDialog.Show("debug",ptRef.ConvertToStableRepresentation(doc));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try something like

```
yourPipe.Location.Curve.GetEndPoint(1)
```

This will give you the XYZ object of the end point of your curve.

Regards,
Arnaud.

Comment: Oh sorry, now I read better your question and see you actually need the Reference.. Indeed I got the same behavior, I don't know why. Sorry!

Comment: Yeah, it's not possible that we can create dimensions based on end points only with objects that belong to structural namespace.